# Recent decline in health contributed to his death

Tags: past-tense

I am lost for a word to replace "recent" if the event (death) happend few years ago - "Recent decline in health contributed to his death". May be I have to use "decline in his health immediately before his death contributed to it" - too wordy.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply go with one of the following, depending on the actual situation:

> A gradual decline in his health led to his death.
>   A slow decline in his health led to his death.
>
> A sudden decline in his health led to his death.
>   A rapid decline in his health led to his death.

Depending on how quickly it came on, you can make some good assumptions about how long prior to his death his health started to fail.

As you had wanted to use *recent* relative to the event, it sounds like either *sudden* or *rapid* would fit.